# How to enable writing to the PCAP_CTRL register in CSU 0xFFCA3008?

Tags: xilinx, petalinux

How to enable writing to the PCAP_CTRL register in CSU 0xFFCA3008? Based on what I read it is a black list register that needs to be enabled by defining SECURE_ACCESS_VAL in the xpfw_config.h. How do that if petalinux_build creates the PMUFW?

I should be able to access read write of the register.